# Wordpress Multisite or not?

Tags: wordpress

I have 4 websites where the main site will be a global site and the other 3 will be variations of the same site, only differing from country to country. They will have the same structures, the same look and feel etc. Only some details and images will change between sites. Is this a good time to use WP Multisite? Thanks.

Comment: Read [this article](http://halfelf.org/2011/dont-use-wordpress-multisite/) to decide if you **don't need to use it**. The author is a MS wizard, you can trust her judgement ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse this is one of the best way to use your site and it is also a great professionalized site because it has other sites for other country. This is better way to do good with site.

Your know if you are in USA then google site will be **google.com**, if you are in india your site will be **google.in** so with this way your site is much better then ever.